# Importing Python Generated JSON file into FLOT.JS

Tags: javascript, json, flot

Please assist me with the code required to use an already generated json file inside of the flot.js code.

I can't seem to find anything about using a file rather than hard coded data into the javascript. I'm sure its pretty simple, its just eluding me!

here is some sample code...
instead of the hard coded plots (var d), I would like to use an external .json file.
I appreciate all the help!

```
$(function() {

    var d = [[-373597200000, 315.71], [-370918800000, 317.45], [-368326800000, 317.50], [-363056400000, 315.86], [-360378000000, 314.93], [-357699600000, 313.19], [-352429200000, 313.34], [-349837200000, 314.67]]; 

    $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
        xaxis: { mode: "time" }
    });

    $("#whole").click(function () {
        $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
            xaxis: { mode: "time" }
        });
    });

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer

    $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the plot function is the data; the possible formats it can take are described at the link below.  I think the Introduction and Data Format sections should give you what you need.

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md

I am not sure what your JSON object looks like, but convert the data in it to a suitable format for the $.plot function.

If you need a bit more background to understand the JavaScript described at the link above, Code School has an introductory, interactive, and free [course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/javascript-road-trip-part-1) on JavaScript.